# Mouse speed faster vertically than horizontally

Tags: 12.04, mouse, display-resolution

This only happens when I use the trackpad. When I try to move the cursor vertically (up and down), the cursor moves very fast. When I move it horizontally, it moves at regular speeds.

My screen size is 1366x768.

Because my screen is 1.77x wider than tall, I went into /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d and added two lines:

Option "HorizResolution" "1"
Option "VertResolution" "1.77"

This did nothing.

Here is the edited section:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchOS "Linux"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
    Option "Ignore" "on"
    Option "HorizResolution" "1"
    Option "VertResolution" "1.77"
EndSection
```

Comment: For the record, mine behaves in the opposite way. That is, its speed is proportional to the dimension by default.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue after upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04, but it looks like it's not related to HorizResolution or VertResolution.

In my case, it was an issue of mouse Acceleration profile (horizontal acceleration faster than vertical).

Just turn it off and compare results:

```
xinput list
xinput set-prop 12 'Device Accel Profile' 0
xinput set-prop 12 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2
```

Where 12 is your mouse pointer device id.

Answer (score 1):

thats because you out the Options in the wrong section. It needs to be in the same InputClass section that shows:
    Driver "synaptics"
If you put it in that one it will work. Also, I don't know if it matters but I multiplied both by 100, just because I wasn't sure if it liked decimals or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem, until I thought of the problem could be my mouse... I licked the laser and it was fixed... Sounds weird but it actually worked. If something doesn't work, unplug it and plug it back or lick it.