# How to change vertical vs horizontal mouse sensitivity?

Tags: 14.04, mouse, logitech

I have a Logitech M570 Wireless Trackball that I have been using for the last year or so. Within the last day, the sensitivity has changed. It seems to have suddenly changed from no scaling (Vertical=Horizontal) to scaling based on monitor dimensions (In my case my monitor is 1366x768 so it ends u being 1.78 to 1). I tried to follow the advice given [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339845/mouse-speed-faster-vertically-than-horizontally) 
 But that didn't help any. What should I do?

Comment: Does the link you provided do anything at all? Can you scale x and y to (say) 10 times, and will that do anything?

Comment: No, nothing there does anything for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not work. It started as a comment, but I need formatting.

I'm not sure if it's important, but my xorg configs are in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, not `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. Also, you know there's a typo in that script in your link, and the last line should be `EndSection`? In any case, try and simplify and just have:

```
Section "InputClass"
    MatchIsPointer "yes"
    Option "HorizResolution" "1"
    Option "VertResolution" "1.77"
EndSection
```

You'd probably want it for all pointers anyway. Again, try with 10 times the values, to see if it works. You'll need to restart (X) for it to work.